# Filter nested objects on client side

Tags: javascript, ajax, d3.js

I have a d3.js scatterplot based off of this: http://bl.ocks.org/nsonnad/4481531

I'm trying to add in a function that would allow you to filter based on (in the case of the example) country (each represented by a color bubble).

The data comes out of a .csv file, but is rendered as an object like this when I console.log it:

```
[0 … 99]
   0: Object
       attribute: "INFJ"
       category: "Personality Type"
       incidence: "1.04"
       index_value: "65"
       main_grouping: "Behaviors"
     __proto__: Object
   1: Object
   2: Object
   3: Object
    ETC...
```

What I want to do is get all of the rows with a specific `main_grouping`. If I do this, I can get a list of all the `main_grouping`s, but that's just step one.

```
d3.csv("example.csv", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        console.log(value.main_grouping);
        });
```

What I don't know how to do with this or from here is to say, given a certain `main_grouping` (that will be selected with a dropdown...I can handle this part though), only return those rows as `data` for use in the rest of the script that renders the scatterplot.

There's not a server-side option here, so I have to figure out something client-side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array `filter`

```
d3.csv("example.csv", function(data) {
data_filtered = data.filter(function(d){
    return d.main_grouping == selected_grouping;
  });
}
```

Comment: Where do I pass in the value I want to filter `main_grouping` with?

Comment: `selected_grouping` can be a variable set by your dropdown menu

Comment: That's what I thought. So, for the rest of my script that was previously using `data`, what do I use now? `d.main_grouping` or `d`? For example, in this, which follows the `return` function: `data.sort(function(a, b) {
            return d3.ascending(a.main_grouping, b.main_grouping);
        })`

Comment: Use the new variable `data_filtered` the same as you would have used `data`. So in your code `data_filtered.sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.main_grouping, b.main_grouping); })`